# Selecting data from large MySQL database where value of one column is found in a large list of values

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I generally use Pandas to extract data from MySQL into a dataframe. This works well and allows me to manipulate the data before analysis. This workflow works well for me.

I'm in a situation where I have a large MySQL database (multiple tables that will yield several million rows). I want to extract the data where one of the columns matches a value in a Pandas series. This series could be of variable length and may change frequently. How can I extract data from the MySQL database where one of the columns of data is found in the Pandas series? The two options I've explored are:

1. Extract all the data from MySQL into a Pandas dataframe (using pymysql, for example) and then keep only the rows I need (using df.isin()).

or

2. Query the MySQL database using a query with multiple WHERE ... OR ... OR statements (and load this into Pandas dataframe). This query could be generated using Python to join items of a list with ORs.

I guess both these methods would work but they both seem to have high overheads. Method 1 downloads a lot of unnecessary data (which could be slow and is, perhaps, a higher security risk) whilst method 2 downloads only the desired records but it requires an unwieldy query that contains potentially thousands of OR statements.

Is there a better alternative? If not, which of the two above would be preferred?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with pandas but strictly speaking from a database point of view you could just have your panda values inserted in a `PANDA_VALUES` table and then join that `PANDA_VALUES` table with the table(s) you want to grab your data from.

Assuming you will have some indexes in place on both `PANDA_VALUES` table and the table with your column the JOIN would be quite fast.

Of course you will have to have a process in place to keep `PANDA_VALUES` tables updated as the business needs change.

Hope it helps.

Comment: that's a good suggestion. However, I need to allow access to the database to multiple users (it's part of a teaching assignment for students) and so modifying a PANDAS_VALUES table for each student may be a tad too complex at this stage. But thanks for the response.

Comment: I would say it all depends how you drive your teaching session. If you have all your students follow up the same exercise at the same time you should be the one to run a script once you move the teaching from one point to another. If each individual student follows up his or her own exercise I would have each exercise prepared with its own `PANDAS_VALUES` populating script and have the `PANDAS_VALUES` table defined as a temporary table whose content will be only available in that student session